# Document.body.innerHTML.replace not working with variable regex string

Tags: javascript, html, regex, google-chrome-extension

The code below should work by replacing every instance of a specific title tag text on a wikipedia page with a href link of a previous title tag. However, nothing seems to be replacing anything. When testing this code with hard-coded values, it works perfectly fine. Console logging shows that everything should be working but it is not. Any help would be appreciated.

```
if (document.title.indexOf("Wikipedia") != -1) {

    var pageHTML = document.body.innerHTML;

    for(var i = 0, l=document.links.length; i<l; i++) {
      //doSomething(document.links[i].href);
      var link = document.links[i].href;
      var title = document.links[i].title;
      if(title != ""){
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        var linkText = document.createTextNode(title);
        a.appendChild(linkText);
        a.title = title;
        a.href = link;
        console.log(typeof title)
        pageHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(title,"g"), a);
      }
    }
    //var finalHTML = "<h1>HELLO<h1>"
    //Appending to DOM
    document.open();
    document.write(pageHTML);
    document.close();

}
```

Comment: What is expected result of `pageHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(title,"g"), a)`?

Comment: it should replace every instance of title with the variable 'a'

Comment: `a` variable at `javascript` at Question is an `<a>` element, not a string. `title` letter or word could appear within tags.

Comment: Please provide examples of desired input and output (i.e. the DOM before and after you code runs).

Comment: You are trying to replace text described by a RegExp with an Element using the string method `.replace()`. That is not going to work.

Comment: This looks like a question which is an [XY problem](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=XY+problem). Please describe in more detail what it is you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: You repeatedly assign `pageHTML` to be a modified `document.body.innerHTML`, but you don't do anything with it prior to re-assigning it.  Only the last assignment (if the `.replace()` worked) would be applied.  All the other assignments would be lost.  Thus, your `for` loop reduces to `var i=document.links.length-1;` and then executing the code once.

Comment: @Makyen, thank you so much!

Comment: @AriJ, Happy to help, but need you to describe, in detail, what you are attempting to achieve. The way that you are going about it is not going to work well, and may not work at all. Taking a fresh look at it from what your goals are is, probably, the best choice (i.e. an [XY problem](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=XY+problem)).

Answer (score 1):

Aside from overwriting `pageHTML` with a single value each iteration, currently you replace the entire page HTML and break its javascript events such as click/hover handlers and many others attached via addEventListener or `.on` properties. Also, you overwrite the entire page thus forcing the browser to parse it entirely and repaint.

The correct approach is to replace just the nodes that contain title text:

```
// title-to-href map used for bulk regexp-replacement
var linkMap = {};
var linkTitles = [];
for (var i = 0, link; (link = document.links[i++]); ) {
    if (link.title) {
        linkTitles.push(escapeForRegex(link.title));
        linkMap[link.title] = link.href;
    }
}
// regexp that matches all titles
var titlesRx = new RegExp(linkTitles.join('|'), 'g');

// iterate all text nodes and build a list of elements that contain titles
var nodesToReplace = [];
var walker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
while (walker.nextNode()) {
    var node = walker.currentNode;
    var newHTML = node.nodeValue.replace(titlesRx, function(title) {
        return '<a href="' + linkMap[title] + '" title="' + title + '">' + title + '</a>';
    });
    if (newHTML != node.nodeValue) {
        nodesToReplace.push({node: node, html: newHTML});
    }
}

// replace the contents of affected elements
var scratchpad = document.createElement('div');
nodesToReplace.forEach(function(info) {
    scratchpad.innerHTML = info.html;
    for (var i = 0, child; (child = scratchpad.children[i++]); ) {
       info.node.parentNode.insertBefore(child, info.node);
    }
    info.node.remove();
});

function escapeForRegex(s) { return s.replace(/[{}()\[\]\/\\.+?^$:=*!|]/g, "\\$&"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing this:-

```
pageHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(title,"igm"), a);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will definitely work if what you meant was replace the title attribute's value with the value from the href attribute of the parent link

```
pageHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(title, link);
```